# How to solve error while doing pip install datawig?

Tags: installation, pip

I'm trying to install [datawig](https://datawig.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/userguide.html) from my Jupyter Notebook, basically:

```
pip install datawig
```

However, I get a huge error output. As it exceeds the characters limit here, let me copy the head:

```
Collecting datawigNote: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [911 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel

  Using cached datawig-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: typing==3.6.6 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from datawig) (3.6.6)
Collecting scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22.1
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.22.1.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting mxnet==1.4.0
  Using cached mxnet-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (21.9 MB)
Collecting pandas==0.25.3
  Using cached pandas-0.25.3.tar.gz (12.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): still running...
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mxnet==1.4.0->datawig) (2.18.4)
Collecting numpy<1.15.0,>=1.8.2
  Using cached numpy-1.14.6.zip (4.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting graphviz<0.9.0,>=0.8.1
  Using cached graphviz-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.3->datawig) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas==0.25.3->datawig) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22.1->datawig) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn[alldeps]==0.22.1->datawig) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas==0.25.3->datawig) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet==1.4.0->datawig) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet==1.4.0->datawig) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet==1.4.0->datawig) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet==1.4.0->datawig) (2.6)
Collecting scipy>=0.17.0
  Using cached scipy-1.9.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (38.6 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36.9 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.8.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36.9 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.7.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (34.3 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.7.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (34.3 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.7.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (33.8 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (32.7 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (32.7 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (32.7 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (32.7 MB)
  Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (31.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn
  Building wheel for pandas (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pandas (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
  Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build pandas numpy scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: numpy, graphviz, scipy, pandas, mxnet, scikit-learn, datawig
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.20.3
    Uninstalling numpy-1.20.3:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.20.3
  Running setup.py install for numpy: started
  Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
  Rolling back uninstall of numpy
  Moving to c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.20.3.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~umpy-1.20.3.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\
   from C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~umpy
  Moving to c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\scripts\f2py-script.py
   from C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-e5jh8elg\f2py-script.py
  Moving to c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\scripts\f2py.exe
   from C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-e5jh8elg\f2py.exe

  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pandas
  copying pandas\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pandas
  copying pandas\testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pandas
```

Which continues with hundreds of lines copying stuff, until the tail of the error, which is preceeded by several errors as the initial ones here:

```
  openblas_lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  openblas_clapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_3_10_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  atlas_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  lapack_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\Alvaro\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w2_fz0zl\numpy_3a3c79a52c1a4b54a4c0ceb99a43e593\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  C:\Users\Alvaro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w2_fz0zl\numpy_3a3c79a52c1a4b54a4c0ceb99a43e593\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE
  
  C:\Users\Alvaro\anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running install
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  building library "npymath" sources
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

numpy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Which I, frankly, don't know how to start handling at all.

Anyone could help me here, please?

Thanks!

Comment: The early stuff about numpy failing (`Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'` and `Rolling back uninstall of numpy`) makes me wonder if this is [this issue](https://github.com/awslabs/datawig/issues/149)?

Comment: its been quite a while but did you manage to find a solution? Or an alternative to datawig?

Comment: Hi @MaxlGemeinderat ,

It's a pleasure to greet you. Regarding your question about installing Datawig, honestly, it's been a while since I faced that issue, and at this moment, I don't quite recall the specific purpose for which I was trying to install it. I might have found an alternative that better suited my needs at that time.

Unfortunately, my memory is not helping me recall the exact details. If you have any other questions or if there's anything else I can assist you with, I'd be happy to try. Thanks for your understanding and patience!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by doing these steps (one for code cell).
**First step**:

```
!git clone https://github.com/awslabs/datawig
```

**Second step**

```
cd datawig
```

**Third step**

```
pip install .
```

Finally

```
import datawig
```